# How to automate browser scrolling for testing scroll interactions?

Tags: javascript, css, macos, google-chrome, parallax

I have a website that uses a number of parallex-y scroll animations, and I'm looking to optimize it.

I'm using the heck out of Chrome devtools timeline tab, but the results are inconsistent because I'm doing the scrolling and I'm human.

I can start and stop the timeline using `console.timeline();` and I can *simulate* a scroll using `$('html, body').animate()`, but when I start `console.timeline()`, it doesn't return FPS

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an interesting article about the topic, it includes code to scroll to the bottom of a page using jQuery, interpret it how you wish;

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-scroll-bottom/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#THEID').click(function(){

        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 'slow');

        return false;

    });

});
```

After you have this script, use an anchor by implementing the element: `<div id="THEID"></div>` to the bottom of your page. By using a link to the anchor at the top of your page, you will be able to slowly scroll. `<a href="#THEID">Click here to scroll down</a>`

or

```
$(document).scrollTop($(document).height());
```

Let me know if this is a simple solution to your issue. If needs be, I can attempt to script a loop which will allow the page to keep scrolling for a set number.